# Selecting zipcode that is stored in string as numberic range (hive)

Tags: sql, string, hadoop, hive, range

I'd like to select people who live in california zipcodes. However this table i'm using stores zipcodes as string, instead of integers, so I havre to put a qutoe around it.

How can I select these values in range, instead of having to type it out? 
I'd like to do something like this: 
`select people from tablename where postal_code >= '90001' and postal_code <= '96162'`

Thank you!

Comment: Did you actually try that query?

Comment: Postal codes aren't, strictly speaking, _numbers_, but rather a collection of digits.  Note too that there are a few zip codes for other states that might be "outside" the normal range, or be in the range for another state, so attempting to use a range in this manner is dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your query would probably work for this specific interval, you would be better off `cast`ing the strings to integers to do proper numeric comparison:

```
select people 
from tablename 
where cast(postal_code as int) between 90001 and 96162
```

String and number comparison do not follow the same rules, and you would eventually get unexpected results by comparing strings. For example, string-wise, `'9'` is greater than `'10'`.